# How to update from Windows Server 2019 Desktop 1809 to 1903 or 1909 on Google Cloud Compute Engine?

Tags: windows, google-app-engine

I've made a Virtual Machine using Google Cloud Compute Engine.

I've searched how to install Windows 10 and figured out that it is way more difficult that I expected.

Google Cloud only gives the possibility to install Windows Server 2019 Datacenter with version 1809 (With desktop version). I'd like to update to version 1909 or 1903. It is possible ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

**You can run Windows 10 on GCE** if you have a licence. Keep in mind that **Windows Server 2019 Datacenter and Windows 10 are quite [different](https://www.howtogeek.com/404763/whats-the-difference-between-windows-and-windows-server/) operating systems** and with own versions and **[Desktop Experience](https://medium.com/@RealNetwork/windows-server-2019-or-2016-server-core-vs-desktop-experience-gui-comparison-standard-datacenter-hyper-v-bb67167fd461) only means that it has GUI interface** in compare to Server Core version. Windows Server 2019 Datacenter with Desktop Experience has no connections to Desktop OS like Windows 10.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows#windows_client) to find more information:

> Bring existing Windows client licenses to Compute Engine using [Bring
>   your own license](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/bring-your-own-license) with sole-tenant nodes and importing your image as a
>   virtual disk. Similar to bringing your license with Windows Server,
>   you must continue to manage license and compliance yourself.
>
> **You can import the following client versions of Windows into Compute
>   Engine**:
>
> - **Windows 10**, versions 1709, 1803, **1903, 1909 (32-bit and 64-bit)**

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/bring-your-own-license#virtual_disk_import_and_image_creation) you can find step by step instruction how to do it:

> **To provision VMs with your existing licenses, you must bring your own media**. Images based on a Google Cloud [premium image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images) are not
>   eligible for BYOL because premium images require pay-as-you-go
>   licenses from Google.
>
> If you have virtual disks (golden disks or golden images) in your
>   on-premises environment with customizations (software configurations,
>   licenses, etc) that you need, the [import virtual disk tool](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks) can
>   help you do the following:
>
> 1. Import your customized virtual disks and create images based on those disks
> 2. Set up the appropriate license configuration
> 3. Install the packages and drivers necessary for compatibility with Google Cloud
>
> The import image workflows are customizable and [available on
>   GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-tools/tree/master/daisy_workflows/image_import). Also, because software from third parties might interfere
>   with the installation of Compute Engine drivers, Google recommends
>   removing third-party software before importing your image.

In general, you're able to use public or custom images on GCE:

> - [Public images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#os-compute-support) are provided and maintained by Google, open-source    communities, and third-party vendors. By default, all projects have access to these images and can use them to create instances.
> - [Custom images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#custom_images) are available only to your project. You can create a custom image from boot disks and other images. Then, use the custom image to create an instance.

And among public images you can choose between [Images with Shielded VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#shielded-images) support and [Images without Shielded VM support](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#unshielded-images).

Comment: As I mentioned above, you should follow documentation https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/bring-your-own-license#virtual_disk_import_and_image_creation . Try to do it step by step and update your question with your steps, commands and outputs.

Comment: I saw that I need to import a virtual disk. I did it with a Windows 10 VHD found there: [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/)

Then imported it in Cloud Storage, and built in "System Image" in GCE. The problem is that it has been canceled, 2 hours weren't enough, here is the last lines from the build:

https://pastebin.com/PEU6j05z

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As I can see at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/bring-your-own-license#virtual_disk_import_and_image_creation when you have an image you should proceed with preparation described at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks and then follow https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks#importing_a_bootable_virtual_disk. Unfortunately, information from  https://pastebin.com/PEU6j05z isn't enough to found the cause of the problem. Please update your question with your all your steps, commands and outputs.

Comment: Ok, created the image, the node, and now I get this error when creating the VM: Instance could not be scheduled due to no matching node with property compatibility.

Any idea why ? Thanks !

Comment: Can you try image  deployed on premises instead of downloaded from Microsoft?