# How to update Windows server 2019 desktop 1809 to 2004 on Google cloud compute engine?

Tags: windows, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

I have created one virtual machine using Google cloud compute engine.

I have researched on how to install windows 10 and I got to know that it is way more difficult to install.

Google cloud only gives the possibility to install windows server 2019 datacenter with version 1809(with desktop version). I'd like to update it to version 2004.

If it is possible. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Server, version 2004 is a [Semi-Annual Channel (SAC)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/servicing-channels-comparison) Release. In our most recent Windows Server SAC releases, we’ve optimized for containers. In this release, we continued improving fundamentals for the core container platform such as performance and reliability. We’ve also worked with .NET team and PowerShell team and further optimized image size and performance for Server Core containers. We will share more details below. On container networking side, we implemented several improvements to allow for better scalability, robustness, and reliability. One example is additional changes and improvements to [Direct Server Return (DSR)](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/networking-blog/direct-server-return-dsr-in-a-nutshell/ba-p/693710).

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Perhaps you can provide some explanation as to how this answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Windows release channel you are using; if Windows has been installed using the Long-Term Servicing Channel (which is based on version 1809), it can't be upgraded. Only versions in the Semi-Annual-Channel can be upgraded.

You can find all the info here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/servicing-channels-comparison.

BTW, this is not specific to GCP; this is valid for all Windows Server installations.

Answer (score 0):

Check  this previous question, they have the same question just different release.

### [How to update from Windows Server 2019 Desktop 1809 to 1903 or 1909 on Google Cloud Compute Engine?](https://serverfault.com/a/1007233)